# frames to movie - matlab windows 7

Tags: matlab, frames, avi

why does the code:

```
aviobj = avifile('example_1.avi', 'compression', 'none', 'fps', 30);  
for i=1:8  
    %generating the filenames  
    filename = strcat('Masks/',int2str(i),'.bmp');   
    I = imread(filename);  
    aviobj = addframe(aviobj,I);                                                 
end  
aviobj = close(aviobj);
```

Works in matlab with windows xp and doesn't work in windows 7. I know that there are other solution to create avi from frame in matlab , but I am puzzeled why it work with on xp and not 7. and it there is something to install so it would work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: it creats a file that windows can not display

Comment: Is it possible to create the files on Win 7 and then watch them on the Win XP? If so, the players on your Win 7 system might lack some AVI codecs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [VideoWriter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html), it's recommended over `avifile`.

Comment: I think VideoWriter doesn't exists in Matlab 2009b